# Сохранение наложенных друг на друга картинок

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

С исправлениями и замечаниями.

Суть дела: из списка выбирается две картинки (одна фотография, другая - рамка для нее). При нажатии на кнопку "сохранить", приложение принудительно закрывается. Eclipse ошибок никаких не  выдает, поэтому не могу понять где что не правильно сделал.

```
void saveIMG() {
    myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/external_sd/My_imgs"); // указываю путь нового файла
    myFile.mkdirs(); // создаю директорию
    tmpc = new Time(); // определяю время для имени новой картинки
    tmpc.setToNow();
    myfilename = "/" + Integer.toString(tmpc.monthDay) + "." + Integer.toString(tmpc.month + 1) + "." + Integer.toString(tmpc.year) + "-" + "MYIMG.jpg"; // имя новой картинки
    myFile = new File(myFile, myfilename); // создаю файл по пути с именем
    try {
        myStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile); // создаю стрим
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        instr1 = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/external_sd/My_imgs/IMG1.jpg"); // стрим для фотографии
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        instr2 = new

        FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/external_sd/My_imgs/IMG2.jpg"); // стрим для картинки
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImageView myview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); // в окне имеется ImageView где должна быть видна новая картинка
    Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inSampleSize = 4; // опция уменьшения рабочих картинок
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instr1, null, opt); // создаю первую картинку, с применением опций
    Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instr2, null, opt); // создаю вторую картинку с применением опций
    newIMG = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(), bitmap1.getConfig()); // прорисовываю новую картинку, которая должна быть в итоге со слоями
    if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        // рисую.
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            canvas = new Canvas(newIMG);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            myview.setImageBitmap(newIMG); // получаю новую картинку и устанавливаю ее в ImageView
        } finally {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saveIMG done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    newIMG.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, myStream); // сохраняю новую картинку
    try {
        myStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        myStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // регистрирую в альбоме
    try {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
        myFile.getAbsolutePath(),
        myFile.getName(),
        myFile.getName());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Не знаю, на каком этапе сделал что-то не правильно, но после нажатия кнопки "сохранить" приложение закрывается, при этом в папке телефона остается "незарегистрированное" изображение 0 byte.

> `E/ActivityManager(71):   35% 71/system_server: 17% user + 18% kernel / faults: 4 minor
> E/ActivityManager(71):     30% 102/InputDispatcher: 8.6% user + 22% kernel
> E/ActivityManager(71):     3.7% 72/HeapWorker: 2.4% user + 1.2% kernel
> E/ActivityManager(71):     1.2% 76/Compiler: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
> E/ActivityManager(71):   1.2% 41/adbd: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
> E/ActivityManager(71):   1.2% 67/logcat: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
> E/ActivityManager(71): 44% TOTAL: 19% user + 25% kernel
> I/InputDispatcher(71): Dropping event because the pointer is not down.`

Comment: Logcat что пишет? Проще говоря - логи в студию!

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: Нужны логи падения, а не вообще все логи. Отфильтруйте логи вашего приложения - скажем по имени пакета что ли... Так ничего невозможно понять.

Comment: @curumb В вопросе информации недостаточно. Нужно привести логи. В них наверняка есть запись исключения, которое вызывает принудительное закрытие, и строчка кода, где это исключение происходит. Кроме того, вы можете пройтись в Eclipse в отладчике по шагам вплоть до того места, где происходит сбой.

Про логгирование можно читать в справке: [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).

Comment: Поставь брейкпоинт, пройдись дебаггером, глянь на какой строке падает.